What was the Mad Men quote where Pete Campbell applauded himself for inventing something that had already been invented?
I'm pretty sure it was season 1-2. He was pretty exasperated, and was trying to justify his worth/creativity and said something along the lines of:

Have you heard of Toaster Strudels? I invented those. It turns out they were already a thing, but I invented them! I came up with the idea all by myself.

What was the episode, and what was the actual quote (I don't think it was actually about Toaster Strudels)?

BTW, it wasn't Toaster Strudels after all, but someone did doctor the footage and took it in a rather similar direction... ;)

New Amsterdam (Season 1, Episode 4).

Pete: I have ideas.
Don: I'm sure you do. Sterling Cooper has more failed artists and intellectuals than the Third Reich.
Pete: You know what? I have good ideas. In fact, I used to carry around a notebook and a pen just to keep track. Direct marketing? I thought of that. Turned out it already existed, but I arrived at it independently.

You can see it here around 0:40:



